# Safari on my iPhone 11 Pro doesn't follow my CSS code anymore after loading the page one time?

Tags: html, css

I have a website I am making for myself, and it works perfectly fine on everything except for Safari on my iPhone 11 Pro, which worked fine the first time I loaded the page but never afterward when I tried to refresh it. With the Chrome app, it even resizes correctly when I change some of the elements and refresh. I left out @media queries for now because I am trying to figure out this issue. Here is my CSS file:

```
    #text, .desc {
    font-family: calibri, times-new-roman;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.topbar {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#headings {
    font-family: arial, times-new-roman;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: candara;
}
table {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
#mypicture {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
th {
    text-align: center;
}   
button {
    height: 2%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: "#34c9eb";
    cursor: pointer;
}

    table {
        border: 3px solid black;
        padding: 1px;
    }
    th {
        border: 3px solid black;
        padding: 1px;
    }
    button {
        width: 100px;
    }





@media print {
    #mypicture {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

I know it's really unorganized, that's just because I was trying to figure out the @meida query for it. Why doesn't my safari change when I adjust, let's say, the table border size? It changes just fine when I refresh on the chrome app or any other device (Chrome on Laptop, Safari on Dad's iPhone 6s, etc). Here is the head portion of my HTML file:

```
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Matthew Vandenberg</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Are you clearing the cache on the iPhone? You can also version the css link `(href="styles.css?vers=1)`, which will force a reload.

Comment: Thank you for this. This solved my issue!